# Permission denied when we use npm start using webpack?

Tags: linux, node.js

The following error will be displayed when i use the command "npm start".

```
> callcenter@0.1.0 start /var/www/html/dev/callcenter
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1013-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! callcenter@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the callcenter@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the callcenter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs callcenter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls callcenter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/dev/callcenter/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: The user callcenter (which executes the script) probably has no access to the path required (/var/www/html). Check permissions on this folder. To validate this is the issue, try to execute this script as root (if possible).

Answer (score 13):

Make sure that your `react-script` binary is executable.

```
$ chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
```

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same issue, Surprisingly it works fine in Windows but failed in Linux giving the same error. Follow below step to resolve this issue.

you need to change `package.json` file inside your project folder like below instead of default value of `"start": "react-scripts start"`

> "scripts": {
>       "start": "`node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start`" }

Answer (score 7):

> Although the OP doesn't really refer to my problem, this was the first *stackexchange* result in Google when searching for `yarn build webpack: Permission denied`, hence I'm adding my solution here in case it helps someone.

For those landing here because they are finding `webpack: Permission denied` when **running `yarn build` on Linux even though the command works fine on Windows**:

The problem in my case was that the `*.lock` files had some relation with the environment in which they were generated (Windows) and wouldn't work in a different environment (WSL2 - Ubuntu)

1. **Remove `node_modules`**

   ```bsh
   rm -vrf node_modules
   ```
2. **Remove locks**

   ```bsh
   rm package-lock.json
   rm yarn.lock
   ```
3. **Run `yarn`**

   ```bsh
   yarn
   yarn build
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your **node_modules** folder and install it again with `npm install`.